# usb-modeswitch update

Tags: usb-modeswitch

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have a modem on stick that is not recoqnized by OS. I search on net and I found out that I need minimum usb-modeswitch-data version 20140529 and usb-modeswitch version 2.2.0-repack0. My Ubuntu version has usb-modeswitch-data version 20140327-1 and usb-modeswitch version 2.1.1-repack0 from http://www.draisberghof.de. I verify on http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch, they release usb-modeswitch-data version 20151101 and usb-modeswitch version 2.2.6. Please send me updated packages or explain me how to do it myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the packages, both usb-modeswitch and data files from the website.

Extract the archive.

Open terminal, and change directories to the extracted folder

To install, run

```
sudo make install
```

Run

```
sudo usb-modeswitch -e
```

to see the version installed.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Thanks Zanna for those corrections, however unnecessary it was!